# best practice response.getOutputStream

Tags: java, servlets

any comments on my code on allowing user to download file.

```
if(fileObject !=null)
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\""+fileObject.getFilename()+"\"");
response.setContentType(fileObject.getFiletype());
response.setContentLength((int)fileObject.getFilesize().intValue());
try {
 if(response !=null && response.getOutputStream() !=null &&fileObject!=null && fileObject.getBinData() !=null ){
    OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    out.write(fileObject.getBinData());
 }


} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new ApplicationRuntimeException(e);
}
```

most of the time, i dont get below error. but once and a while, i get error

```
29 Nov 2010 10:50:41,925 WARN [http-2020-2] - Unable to present exception page: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:610)
```

Comment: you state that this has something to do with tapestry, however there is no reference to anything tapestry in your question. please explain how this is tapestry related or remove the tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exception message is clear:

> **Unable to present exception page**: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
>   at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.**getWriter**(Response.java:610)

An `IOException` was been thrown and you're rethrowing it as a custom exception which forced the servletcontainer to show the exception page which will use `getWriter()` for this. You should in fact let any `IOException` go because that's usually a point of no return.

An `IOException` can for example be thrown during the job when the client aborted the request. The best practice is to **not** catch `IOException` on the Servlet API yourself. It's already declared in `throws` clause of the servlet methods.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    FileObject fileObject = getItSomehow();
    if (fileObject != null && fileObject.getBinData() != null) {
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileObject.getFilename() + "\"");
        response.setContentType(fileObject.getFiletype());
        response.setContentLength((int)fileObject.getFilesize().intValue());
        response.getOutputStream().write(fileObject.getBinData());
    } else {
        // ???
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are calling `response.getOutputStream()` twice.  Instead, call it once and assign it to a local variable, then use that variable for your null check and your `write` operation.

```
try {
 OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
 if(response !=null && out !=null &&fileObject!=null && fileObject.getBinData() !=null ){
    out.write(fileObject.getBinData());
 }
} catch (IOException e) {
  throw new ApplicationRuntimeException(e);
}
```

Comment: That's not the cause of the problem. You can call `getOutputStream()` and `getWriter()` each as many times as you want, but **not both** on the *same* response.

Answer (score 0):

How can response be null? Especially after you've already used it? Or response.getOutputStream()? Or fileObject, after you've already tested it for being non-null? And used it? These tests may be doing more harm than good.

Comment: This should have been a comment, not an answer. It namely doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I disagree. See the last sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I always defer to well tested code when I can ...

http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/commons/fileupload/util/package-summary.html